# Infinite loop in pso cluster algorithm

Tags: c++, cluster-analysis, particle-swarm

I am having some trouble with clusters. I am doing some self learning for my course and I wanted to try out a clustering algorithm. This is not my homework.

When I execute this code, which seems perfectly logical,  the value `&p[]` always returns 0 and hence the loop becomes infinite.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)//nc stands for number of clusters
{
    int flag = 1;
    Particle * temp;
    while (flag != 0)
    {
        temp = &p[rand() % n];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (cluster[i].c.find(temp) != cluster[i].c.end())// 
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
    }
```

//copy temp to cluster
}

Can somebody tell me what mistake I have made? Or if you have any other suggestions, you can post it here. I would really like to have some new perspective other than mine.

EDIT:
As there was no other reasonable answers, I tried rewriting the program, and it was resolved.

Comment: I think you have missed one closing paranthesis. And please edit the post. It is very clumsy.

Comment: @Venkatesh I've not given entire code,this only part of it. I think some logical error is there.

Comment: it is infinite loop problem , now here is the prblem, while your i =0, j=0 your loop is getting infinite bcoz you are not entering in second for loop. and your flag is not getting zero.

Comment: if i can see your whole code, would bring more light to your problem.
so if you can fork your code in ideone.com

Comment: i have removed the second for loop, yet, it is still infinite loop.

Comment: i need to see how does it looks like after you removed second loop? there could be other problem raising after removing second loop.

Comment: I forked the code in ideone.com

Comment: you can find it here [link] (http://ideone.com/CoC1Sz)